# How to change Option one value to selected after a click event or after an onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Using this code to change the option value but it doesn't work !

JavaScript

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function changeDefaultSelection(){
           $("#selectVehicle").val('1');
       }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<html>
   <select id="selectVehicle">
      <option  value="0"> Please Select A Vehicle </option>
      <option  value="1"> Car </option>
      <option  value="2"> Bus </option>
   </select>
<button onclick="changeDefaultSelection()"> Change me</button>
</html>
```

Comment: you didn't called your function

Comment: Yes , I just forgot it to add it , but actually i used it in my code

Comment: Your code works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/p6mf7q88/ If it doesn't work on your actual web page, please check the browser's dev console for errors.

Comment: Click of what? Simply provide this function to onclick of whatever..

Comment: Actually this code works for me without any error

Comment: What is your requirement? Actually on the button click currently the selected option changes to 'Car'. What is your exact requirement?

Comment: @VishnuSadanandan  your code is working fine then

Comment: @VishnuSadanandan What error have you seen in your console?

Comment: I have a room booking section with two type RENTAL / BUY. on creating / editing this type list , one can simply change the list type as Rental / Buy , as a result some of fields must change dynamically on selecting the type. If Rental selected , the default value of checkin time which is again a select tag must change to say 10 : 00 am , and If Buy selected the default checkin time must change to 8 : 00 am. So I wrote the code on the on change of RENTAL / BUY  . . .I can fix all Other text fields according to this onchange , but i couldn't change the checkin select tags default value.

Answer (score 1):

Use prop to add the selected attribute:

```
$('body').on('click','button',function(){
 $('#selectVehicle option[value="1"]').prop('selected',true);
});
```

```js
$('body').on('click','button',function(){
  $('#selectVehicle option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectVehicle">
      <option  value="0"> Please Select A Vehicle </option>
      <option  value="1"> Car </option>
      <option  value="2"> Bus </option>
   </select>
<button> Change me</button>
```

Comment: Why? Using `.val()` as shown in the question works perfectly well with less code: https://jsfiddle.net/p6mf7q88/

Comment: i have never seen someone using var to change a select, its a little bit confusing if you ask me

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
function changeDefaultSelection(){
       $("#selectVehicle").val('1').change();
   }
```

Comment: What difference does `.change()` make? There is no change handler on the select element.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
           $("#selectVehicle").val("1").addclass('selected');
```

and use double quotes. This works for me.

Comment: what scope does the function at the end do exactly?

Comment: it adds the class "selected" to the item having value "1" of dropdown "selectedvehicle"

Comment: what does this class "selected" do?

Comment: so the "selected" class is a custom class that shows that value of dropdown as selected, can you show me a example of this custom class?

Comment: The code shown in this answer adds the class `'selected'` to the `#selectVehicle` element, i.e., the `<select>`, not the `<option>`, and in any case there is no built-in `'selected'` class available in HTML/CSS so this has no effect. Double or single quotes make no difference (and also you said to use double but then didn't follow that advice yourself).

Comment: No its built in class.